# Как реализовать поиск почты в сети на Python 3?

Tags: python-3.x, email, requests, urllib, smtplib

То есть: пользователь вводит свою почту `mail = str(input('Please, enter your email:'))`, но пользователь может ввести всё, что угодно, для этого нужно убедиться, что такая почта действительно есть.
Находил в сети сервис mailtester.com, но судя по всему он не работает:
1. Реальные адреса электронной почты вбивал безрезультатно.
2. Старенький интерфейс сайта говорит о том, что его скорее всего давненько не обновляли.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну модеш попробивать отправлять на пошту смс пароль которий он будет вводить или спробувать отправить смс 1 це проверь чи заканчивається типу на @gmail.com
Вот то что тебе нужно https://2ip.ru/mail-checker/
Вбиваєш бот или как там  и зчитуєш !
Єсли нада  переспроси єсли не понятна подскажу!

Comment: Большое спасибо!